# Why are the rows missing?

Tags: sql, database, teradata

Is there any tool or method or something else which can help me with analysis of the process.
The process contains around 15 steps and each job step is represented with one SQL script. I am working with Teradata.

Here is my problem - the colleague of mine has changed one of the SQL scripts. This change caused some addition of some new rows. The problem is - the added rows are not seen at the end of the process in the final report.

Since there are a lot of tables, joins, filtering inside this process (15 sql scripts) I can't grasp all the process and find the answer why are those rows missing in the final report?

Therefore, is there any piece of software, method or some suggestion from your side about what should I do to find the answer on the question "Why are the rows missing".

Comment: I would suggest looking at the SQL queries.

Comment: Can we see the code so we can check `Why are rows missing` ?

Comment: Maybe you're not describing it very well, but when I read this question what I get is: "There's something wrong in the code.  But I don't want to bother looking at the code or debugging it to try to figure it out.  What else should I do?"  If your colleague modified something and the desired behavior was not achieved, your colleague probably needs to continue to modify it until the desired behavior is achieved.

Comment: You got the wrong impression. I am analysing the code, and actually I am doing it for 5-6 days. No - unfortunately the colleague who modified the code can't continue to work on it, so I have to do it. 
Another difficulty is that I can't send you the scripts - my employer would not approve that. 
Because I am analysing the scripts for 5-6 days, and I didn't figured out whyare the rows missing, I wanted to ask someone who was in the same situation - what did he/she did. Is there any visualization software or something like that that could held me in finding the answer or some other method...

Comment: Since the process has around 15 steps/SQL queries, and addition of the ew steps happens in 4. step, things get toooo complicated because all joins, inserting the referenced data into new tables, then again filtering the data...

Comment: As @Hogan already commented, the usual approach is to take a look into each of the queries to locate the one that is making those rows to dissapear and then correct it.

Comment: If you can't look at the queries to figure out how they are failing then you need to hire a consultant who understands SQL.

Comment: you didn't tell me anything new, not recommended any software or some method. your recommendation was - look at SQL. As I told - I am doing that for the last 5 days. I'll have to find answers somewhere else.

Comment: -1 this is completely unanswerable with the information given - Rob's valiant effort notwithstanding

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest introducing a series of volatile tables in your script(s) that you can use to help debug each SQL statement that runs to confirm the changes that are occurring. Volatile tables are created within a users spool space so there is no need for you to ask your DBA team for perm space or additional privileges in another database to create these tables.

Once you have volatile tables in place you can start to query the volatile tables and compare the results in a spreadsheet in an effort to track the changes that are occurring from one step or script to the next. Pay particular attention to data types, NULL vs NOT NULL, and JOIN  conditions. A subtle difference between data types may be enough to cause something to fail an equality condition and thus drop the record out.

**Edit:**
Have you looked at the EXPLAIN plan to see if the optimizer is taking what is written to be an OUTER JOIN and converting it to an INNER JOIN? If you have any OUTER JOINs in your logic you have to be careful with how you qualify on the table participating in the OUTER JOIN. If you place the criteria in the WHERE clause the optimizer may re-write your join as an INNER JOIN. This could cause rows to fall out of the LEFT or RIGHT side of the JOIN depending on the JOIN you have written.

Teradata has a Visual Explain tool that I have not found to be much use. I find what Oracle and SQL Server can produce to be much more intuitive to use since they are built into the query tool. Visual Explain requires you to load a QCD database and then point the tool at it. Cumbersome to me at best. I find it easier to trace the EXPLAIN plan. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Rob, thanks for a decent answer. The problem is - I have more or less tried to analyse it that way. But the thing is - it gets out of control 2-3 steps after the change is occured. I got a suggestion from my colleagues to indentify the new-added rows and then to select one and then to go step-by-step to find the place that is filtering the rows. I have identified the rows that are filtered out, but when I try the method my colleague suggested, I get stuck because things get too complicated - part of the rows is taken, then  joins are made, than that is transfered to another table, ...

Comment: Therefore, I thought to myself - is there some software (hopefuly Teradata's) that can help me visualize the entire proces - so I could see which steps affect the critical rows. Or, since I am working with Teradata for a month, what do you experts do in this situations? Just analysing plain old SQL scripts? i thought to myself - there must be some tool that simplifies this analysis... Right?

Comment: @Rob: Have you actually seen this behaviour? (*" the optimizer is taking what is written to be an OUTER JOIN and converting it to an INNER JOIN"*) That would be a bug.

Comment: And the other part: *" If you place the criteria in the WHERE clause the optimizer **may** re-write your join as an INNER JOIN."* That is not "may", it is done this way. If the WHERE criteria include the outer table, the results in that case are always as if it was an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Cade Yes, you may be right. Still, the wording is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, how do you even know that the rows are missing?  This is a serious question.  How do you have confidence in the expected output in the first place if you don't understand the process?  If you explore from that point, and understand why you are confident that the rows are missing, that should lead you backwards to understanding.

There is no magical tool which can simply reverse engineer SQL which is too complex to understand.

Since you have a behavior before and after the change by your colleague, I would take snapshots of all the intermediate tables before and after the change.

Then simply compare the rows to see what is different.

Presumably at some point in the intermediate tables they will start or stop deviating between the before and after.  That script is then obviously the first culprit.

Repeat until output is as desired.